# How to Make popup.html on specific URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

PopUp.html doesn't work on specific URL
I want to enable popup.html to open on a specific URL just Like google.com for example

*Manifest.json v3*

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My Extension",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["popup.js"],
      "css": ["style.css"]
    }
  ],"action": { 
      "default_popup" : "Popup.html"
    }
}
```

I tried with MV2 but it can't work inside the if condition()

*Manifest.json v2*

```
{
  "name": "testmv2",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My Extension 2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["activeTab","tabs", "declarativeContent"],
      "background":{        
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["popup.js"],
      "css": ["style.css"]
    }
  ],    "browser_action": { }
}
```

*Backgound.js*

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

'use strict';

chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    myFunction(tab.url);
});

function myFunction(tablink) {
var mySiteUrl = 'https://www.google.com/';

    if( tablink === mySiteUrl){
        //it's the right website
        chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "Popup.html"});

    }
}
})
```

Comment: Background scripts run in a separate context from any webpage loaded in a tab so listening to `DOMContentLoaded` on `document` will have no effect. You can use the `chrome.tabs` API to listen to tab updates via [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onUpdated) instead.

Answer (score 0):

## This answer is supported in mv3.

> As @bradcush said, you cannot use normal `addEventListener` in background.js. To keep it simple, background.js is more like server.js with no direct access to DOM element.

In your context, you will need to

1. `addListener` on [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onUpdated:%7E:text=changed%20inside%20of.-,onUpdated,-chrome.tabs.onUpdated) for change in tab
2. if the current tab's url is what you want, [`setPopup`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#method-setPopup:%7E:text=to%20callback.-,setPopup,-chrome.action.setPopup)
3. else `setPopup` to empty.

```js
// background.js

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {

    // Additionally, you can check for changeInfo.status

    if (/^https:\/\/www.google.com/.test(tab.url)) {  
        chrome.action.setPopup({ popup: "./popup.html"})
    } else {
        chrome.action.setPopup({ popup: "" })
    }
});
```

## For mv2

You will need to make corresponding change according to [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/).

Comment: This setPopup is not working for me. It's not even throwing any error. Could you please tell what can be done?